# static void Main(string[] args)

Tags: c#, .net, parameters, console

For the start up method of the console application `static void Main(string[] args)`, 
assuming that the parameters are passed as below:

helloworld a , b , c, d

What is the best way to pick up a, b, c and d from agrs (without space and comma) ?

Comment: -1: Please don't change the nature of the question after answers have already been posted. The removal of the quotes invalidates all the answers below.

Answer (score 3):

```
string[] s = args[0].Split(new char[] { ' ', ',' }, 
                           StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Comment: Isn't args[0] the program name?

Comment: @Dirk no, `args[0]` contain first parameter

Comment: @Dirk: It's the program name in C, but not in .NET.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I thought it would be the same.

Comment: with the parameter likes this "a , b , c, d" the args has 6 elements
args[0] = "a"
args[1] = ","
args[2] = "b"
args[3] = ","
args[4] = "c,"
args[5] = "d" Do we need to do the same for all part of args?

Comment: I am sorry, my question is helloworld a , b , c, d

Answer (score 1):

```
var elements = args[0].Split(',').Select(s => s.Trim());
```

Comment: This might be a better answer than mine if the elements can contain internal spaces which need to be preserved. However, `args` should read `args[0]`.

Comment: Thanks Douglas, I'll make the changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Trim()` to remove space and `Replace()` to replace comma separated values.

Comment: with the parameter likes this "a , b , c, d" the args has 6 elements
args[0] = "a"
args[1] = ","
args[2] = "b"
args[3] = ","
args[4] = "c,"
args[5] = "d"  Do we need to do the same for all part of args?

Comment: thanks you so 
foreach(var element in agrs)
{
  if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(element.Trim().Replace(",", string.Empty))
    continue;
  //do something
}

is that okay?